# I want to open one from and hit button present on that form from another form in a loop. I have tried below code

Tags: c#

Code in first form:

```
int i=0;
while(i < 5)
{
    this.hide();
    form2 obj_form2 = new form2();
    obj_form2.show();
    i++;
}
```

I have to put some value in textbox present in form2 and on button click i want to pass value of that textbox from form2 to form1 five times. Though above code i am getting all the five window in one time but i want them to show one by one on hitting button click of form2

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can remove the while loop and keep a class variable to detect the number of times you presses the button:

```
private pressimes = 0;

private void btnOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.hide();
   form2 obj_form2=new form2();
   obj_form2.PassedValue = pressTimes;
   obj_form2.show();
   pressTimes++;

}
```

In form 2, add :

```
public int PassedValue  { set; get; }
```

and use it inside the form as the passed value. Or you can change your form 2 constructor and pass the value using : `form2 obj_form2=new form2(pressTimes)`

Answer (score -1):

This is the code to put in your `Form1`:

```
this.hide();
List<string> results = new List<string>(); // List of all the returned results

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    form2 obj_form2 = new form2();
    obj_form2.ShowDialog();

    results.Add(obj_form2.textBox.Text);
}

this.Show();
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", results)); // Show all the results
```

Now, in your `Form2`, find the textBox in which you write the return value. Select that and look at it's properties. Find the property `Modifiers` and set it to `public`.

Now this code should work. I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You could also add this function to `Form2`:

```
public static string GetInput()
{
    form2 obj_form2 = new form2();
    obj_form2.ShowDialog();

    return obj_form2.textBox.Text;
}
```

And change the previously mentioned code to this

```
this.hide();
List<string> results = new List<string>(); // List of all the returned results

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    results.Add(form2.GetInput());

this.Show();
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", results)); // Show all the results
```

Do still change the `Modifiers` property mentioned before